# Ubuntu: Can you switch to admin from guest account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, sudo

Screen went out in laptop and I have a second external screen connected.  Ubuntu doesn’t recognize the second screen until logged in. I dual boot with Ubuntu as default after timeout and would like to edit the Grub boot loader to default to Windows, I think I remember it recognizing second screen before log in and would like to disable primary and see if I can log in on external screen.

In Ubuntu guest cannot `sudo` or `su` so I am unable to edit the Grub. Is there a way around this or am I SOL? Is there any way to log in as a guest to get screen up then switch to non-temp workspace?

```
errors:
su setgid: Operation not permitted

sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: What commands are you using for su and sudo ?  Why log in as guest and not the regular user account (which will, presumably be in the adm group and able to use sudo)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use single user mode or append `init=/bin/bash` to your boot entry to login to a root shell (https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)
2. `ctrl+alt+F1` and start TTY > login with your account with use sudo privileges (http://www.stuckngo.com/how-to-run-sudo-command-from-guest/)
3. Use liveCD linux and edit Grub. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd